# Jquery result is not coming without alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I did a live search function Laravel 7 using jquery. I used the keyup function. I have written the code tested each and every time for the keypress the alert is working and result also coming but I stop the alert search result is coming I tried the keypress & keydown event also same issues. I don't what is the issue please help me to solve this issue.

```html
<form id="small-search-box-form" action="{{route('MainSearchProduct')}}" method="get">
 <input type="text" class="search-box-text" id="search_query" name="search" placeholder="Search store" />
 <input type="submit" class="button-1 search-box-button" value="Search" />
 <ul class="search-drop" id="result">
    
 </ul>
</form>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var input_search = $('#search_query');
  input_search.keyup(function() {
    //alert(input_search.val());
    var query = input_search.val();
    $.ajax({
      url: "{{ route('MainSearchQuery') }}",
      type: "GET",
      data: {
        'proSearch': query
      },
      success: function(data) {
        $('#result').html(data);
      }
    }, 10000);
  });
  $(document).on('click', 'li', function() {
    var value = $(this).text();
    $('#search').val(value);
    $('#result').html("");
  });
});
```

[image]

Comment: Result is not coming are you saying from backend ?

Comment: You posted almost all front-end code.  Why not make it runnable?  You'll get to the bottom of it faster.  Use some dummy values for your variables and you can see if the problem is on your server or not.

Comment: This is running with laravel. The result is coming when an alert is there if I comment the alert search is not working.

Comment: If you want I will attach the controller and the route.

Comment: Also , you have given time limit `10000` remove that and see if that works .

Comment: No after i removed the limit also same